# moveit_planning_execution fails

Tags: moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i have developed the moveit configuration file for ABB IRB4600 robot by following http://wiki.ros.org/Industrial/Tutorials/Create_a_MoveIt_Pkg_for_an_Industrial_Robot  but i am not able to launch the moveit_planning_execution ..i am getting the following error.

[image: Screenshot from 2017-03-07 05^%43^%49.png]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/256375/moveit_planning_execution-fails/) by [Muneeb](https://answers.ros.org/users/29399/muneeb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2017-03-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-03-07**:
Don't post errors as images, there is **no** need to do that. Copy-paste the error text directly into your questions and format it using the *Preformatted Text* button (the one with `101010` on it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!
When that error happens, that means that the compiler didnt find the package. So is it the package name correct? Did you compile, using "catkin_make", after creating the moveit_config package? did you write on the terminal "source devel/setup.sh"?

---

Originally posted by [FábioBarbosa](https://answers.ros.org/users/29070/f%C3%A1biobarbosa/) with karma: 137 on 2017-03-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Muneeb](https://answers.ros.org/users/29399/muneeb/) on 2017-03-07**:
Thanks ..now it works fine.. i answer above .